# how do i add background music to auto play in the background of my vb project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a project in vb 2010 that im working on. I want to know if i publish this and make it downloadable when it is done will my background music be heard by others?

Im pretty sure it's only playing on mine because the song is on my computer right?

Is there a code to make it so it stays even if i make this program downloadable?

Comment: How did you implement your background music?  Is your file linked in as a resource, or just a file?

Comment: I did not add it yet until i am sure it will work. But from the tuts i have seen it will be added by putting it in my resources. Is this the correct method to make it stay, after it is uploaded and someone download my program?

Comment: One way to try this is to set up a virtual machine using [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) or something, install your program there (it's like using a whole new computer), and then you can see whether it works or not.

Comment: Files added as resources are compiled into the EXE itself, and are always available to the program.  However, this isn't typically done for large resources, unless you have a reason to do so.  It is completely acceptable to leave such files out of the EXE and distribute them within your installer program, so that they get copied to the program's directory once installed.

Comment: so then yes it can be done? I'll will only be adding one song to autoplay. One song should not be a large resource right?

Comment: How large it is depends on the codec (and nitrate), along with the length of the song. Still, for your typical MP3 it's likely less than 5MB... which isn't very large, **but**, your application is likely just a few dozen KB (1MB is about a thousand times larger than a KB). It's always going to be a judgement call whether it's a good decision or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the background music distributed with the program. It should be possible to include the music file as a resource in your project, and then to pass that resource to what you use to play the audio.

Alternatively, you could simply package the music file with your executable (whether you're using a zip or an installer), and then find the file in the same directory as your application, and play it that way.